# Regular expression for Apache substitute

Tags: regex, apache, sed

To convert wp-admin to acceso08 is working in normal cases, but
in cases like #wp-admin: xx  is not working.

Substitute `s|wp-admin|acceso08|n`

Comment: What is the `n` flag? Apart from that, what's not working?

Comment: please edit your post to show sample input, required output, the code you have tried so far, and error messages (verbatim) and any output you are getting, with a description of what is wrong. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the 'g' flag at the end.

```
sed -e 's|wp-admin|acceso08|g' input_file > output_file
```

Details on the g flag: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-6